# In Settings>>General I am missing some fields

Tags: urls, options

I am new to Wordpress and downloaded the 3.5.1 version from my hosting provider.  I want to add www in front of my domain and I read from many sources how to do this. Go to settings then general and change it there.  Thats fine except my screen in General looks nothing like the instructions I have been following

It does not have a place to change the Site or Wordpress URL.  Am I missing something
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the wrong settings page. Your site is a multi-site setup; the URL is set in the site manager, not in individual sites.

Go to **Network Admin/Sites** in the **My Sites** menu:

[image]

Select a site to edit:

[image]

Change the URL:

[image]

#### Update

You need a subdomain setup to get editable URLs.

See [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) for the installation guide and [Configuring Wildcard Subdomains](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains) for the server setup.

Comment: +1 From your answer i see where I was going wrong and I can now navigate to the right place. However, In my info tab the ability to change my domain url is diabled.  When I go to settings tab its the same for the site url and the home url

Comment: Ah, I see. You need a subdomain setup, not a sub-site setup to be able to change the complete URL.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, is there documentation or instructions you can point me to help me achieve this?  If you add your comment to your answer i will accept

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your hosting provider auto-installs a modified version of WordPress.

You should consult them, or remove this install entirely, and do a manual install in its place.

EDIT: I defer to Toscho.

Comment: +1  This doesnt answer my question however it is a useful piece of information from someone like me who is new to WP.  Please explain the benefits of doing what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using a wordpress website hosted on wordpress.com. The tutorials your are following are for the wordpress you download and install it yourself.

Comment: I have both wordpress.com and the wordpress self installed that you get at wordpress.org. The settings pages are indeed different.

Comment: I am using a hosted site with wordress.org, not,com